# Time complexity of algorithm with random component (Gillespie Algorithm)

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I'm trying to find the time complexity of the Gillespie Algorithm.

General algorithm can be found: [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gillespie_algorithm#Algorithm)

More extended version: [Here](http://one-its-webapp1.transport.utoronto.ca/c/document_library/get_file?p_l_id=46711&folderId=52907&name=DLFE-924.pdf)

The assumption is that the number of reactions and the number of proteins is constant. This might allow me to calculate the time complexity by the time variable alone.

But I get stuck since the time increase each iteration is based on a random value. Let me elaborate (removed non relevant code):

So this is the general loop, each iteration the reactions are updated, then the currentTime is updated.

```
currentTime = 0.0;
while(currentTime < timeEnd)
{
    reactions->calcHazard();
    currentTime += this->getNextTime();
}
```

The function getNextTime calculates a new time.

```
double Gillespie::getNextTime()
{
    double randVal;

    randVal = ((double) rand() / (double)(RAND_MAX));
    while ( randVal == 0)
    {
        randVal = ((double) rand() / (double)(RAND_MAX));
    }
    return ((1.0/reactions->getSum())*(log(1.0/randVal)));
}
```

The calculation of a the new time size is based on a random value R. The other variable component here is the result of reactions->getsum. The return value of this function is

```
sum(k*A(t))
```

Where k and A(t) are both vectors, k is the probability for each reaction and A(t) is the number of proteins at time t.

Better explanation about the time increase might be provided by page 7 of previous link.

Is it possible to say anything about the time complexity of this (iteration from tStart -> tEnd)? Or is this impossible without also including information about about #proteins and #reactions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's  `O(n)`.  You don't really need to calculate the expected return value of `getNextTime()`.  It's enough to know that its return doesn't change in response to the simulation running.

Let's assume your code iterates that loop `N` times for a `1 hour` simulation.

It's pretty obvious that these are equivalent...

```
timeEnd = currentTime + 2hours;
while (currentTime < timeEnd) { ... } // ??? iterations
```

is equivalent to

```
timeMid = currentTime + 1hour;
timeEnd = currentTime + 1hour;
while (currentTime < timeMid) { ... }  // N iterations
while (currentTime < timeEnd) { ... } // <=N iterations
```

So, it iterates the loop approx `2N` times for a `2 hour` simulation.

> The assumption is that the number of reactions and the number of proteins is constant

That is useful assumption.  Basically, that means that `getNextTime()` will not systematically increase or decrease as the simulation runs.  If the return value of `getNextTime()` decreased over the course of the simulation (meaning A(t) was increasing over the course of the simulation), then the second loop would take more iterations than the first one.

You can probably make that assumption anyways if the system hits equilibrium at some point (that's inevitable right?  I'm not a chemist).  Because then A(t) is constant, since that's... what equilibrium is.

Comment: I might made the number of proteins incorrectly. The number of different proteins does not change. However the amount for each protein does grow or shrink. Input of the program is (T,P,R,Rc), with T=time, P=number of different proteins, R=Possible reactions with their corresponding reaction change.

So A(t) will always be able to change, and I cannot take the assumption that an equilibrium is ever achieved. It might also go in an oscillating state.

However I do think you are right about that for an larger N (endtime) the amount of work needed for each iteration stays the same! Missed that, ty